# Switch window split orientation, fastest way

Tags: buffers, window

Say you have two buffers open like so:

```
------------------------------------
            |                      |
  buffer 1  |        buffer 2      |       
            |                      |
------------------------------------
```

What's the fastest way to switch the buffers so that you get this:

```
------------------------------------
           buffer 1                |
                                   |
------------------------------------
            buffer 2               |
                                   |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546694/. transpose-frame library. Disclaimer - haven't tried it.

Comment: There's a wiki page on this topic: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5371; in particular one answer mentions `transpose-frame` on MELPA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a defun that would do what you are looking for:

```
(defun toggle-window-split ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= (count-windows) 2)
      (let* ((this-win-buffer (window-buffer))
             (next-win-buffer (window-buffer (next-window)))
             (this-win-edges (window-edges (selected-window)))
             (next-win-edges (window-edges (next-window)))
             (this-win-2nd (not (and (<= (car this-win-edges)
                                         (car next-win-edges))
                                     (<= (cadr this-win-edges)
                                         (cadr next-win-edges)))))
             (splitter
              (if (= (car this-win-edges)
                     (car (window-edges (next-window))))
                  'split-window-horizontally
                'split-window-vertically)))
        (delete-other-windows)
        (let ((first-win (selected-window)))
          (funcall splitter)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))
          (set-window-buffer (selected-window) this-win-buffer)
          (set-window-buffer (next-window) next-win-buffer)
          (select-window first-win)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))))))
```

(Shamelessly copied from [Magnars .emacs.d](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/defuns/buffer-defuns.el))

Plus if you call it again, it will re-split your windows in the original vertical orientation.

Comment: It would be nice if this could preserve the relative size relationship of the two windows. I often keep an uneven "short" window on the bottom, and when switching back and forth, it would be helpful to preserve this relative size. Although a narrow vertical window is probably less useful.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I use this. So helpful.

Comment: only works if you have no more than 2 windows `(if (= (count-windows) 2)`. Tranpose-frame support unlimited windows.