# How to change Emacs windows from vertical split to horizontal split?

Tags: window

```
Window A
++++++++
Window B
```

Is there a way to switch to

```
Window A : Window B
```

Is there a way to switch view without closing windows?

Comment: With the large screens of today, why would one ever want to run something other than side-by-side windows? I use six windows spread out over two monitorns -- I use https://github.com/Lindydancer/multicolumn to set up the windows when I start Emacs and have configured most of my packages to reuse existing windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch window split orientation, fastest way](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/318/switch-window-split-orientation-fastest-way)

Comment: @Lindydancer it's not a good idea to second guess other people's needs based on your HW utilisation.  How about some people stack monitors rather than have them side by side? ;)

Comment: Sometimes when your killing windows you end up with them vertically stacked and you'd like to get to get side by side. Every once in a while you want to compare two very long lined files and it also helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a simple function that will toggle between a horizontal and vertical split.  It assumes you've only got two windows, and doesn't do any resizing:

```
(defun window-split-toggle ()
  "Toggle between horizontal and vertical split with two windows."
  (interactive)
  (if (> (length (window-list)) 2)
      (error "Can't toggle with more than 2 windows!")
    (let ((func (if (window-full-height-p)
                    #'split-window-vertically
                  #'split-window-horizontally)))
      (delete-other-windows)
      (funcall func)
      (save-selected-window
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))))))
```

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, there's a [`tranpose-frame` package on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeFrame) that will allow you to transpose the whole frame, as well as do other transformations (rotate by by 180 degrees; rotate by 90 degrees clockwise or counterclockwise; flip horizontally or vertically).

Answer (score 21):

The `transpose-frame` package is available on [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/transpose-frame) as well.

Use `M-x transpose-frame`, or bind it to something to accomplish this.

Comment: `MELPA` link broken?

Comment: Fixed the link.