# Switching between horizontal and vertical splitting?

Tags: window-splitting

From time to time, by mistake, I split my screen vertically `C-x 3` (binded to `split-window-right`), whereas I originally wanted a horizontal splitting `C-x 2` (binded to `split-window-below`).

**Question:** is there a function to switch between vertical <-> horizontal splitting?

*note:* for the moment, I hide the buffer `C-x 0` and re-split with the right `C-x 2` (instead of `C-x 3`) and reselect the buffer... which is clearly not optimal.

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5371/how-to-change-emacs-windows-from-vertical-split-to-horizontal-split

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the following for this:

```el
(defun toggle-window-split ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= (count-windows) 2)
      (let* ((this-win-buffer (window-buffer))
             (next-win-buffer (window-buffer (next-window)))
             (this-win-edges (window-edges (selected-window)))
             (next-win-edges (window-edges (next-window)))
             (this-win-2nd (not (and (<= (car this-win-edges)
                                         (car next-win-edges))
                                     (<= (cadr this-win-edges)
                                         (cadr next-win-edges)))))
             (splitter
              (if (= (car this-win-edges)
                     (car (window-edges (next-window))))
                  'split-window-horizontally
                'split-window-vertically)))
        (delete-other-windows)
        (let ((first-win (selected-window)))
          (funcall splitter)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))
          (set-window-buffer (selected-window) this-win-buffer)
          (set-window-buffer (next-window) next-win-buffer)
          (select-window first-win)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))))))
```

I picked that up from [Magnars Sveen](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/a4e905990a2b212c531636d318a16d75ff6800bf/defuns/buffer-defuns.el#L42) of [Emacs Rocks](http://emacsrocks.com/) fame.

Comment: Thanks! Just tested it, it works. I will wait a little to see if other solutions working with more than 2 windows are suggested.

Comment: sure thing. I never thought about this until Magnars mentioned it somewhere, and now it's indispensible. For tweaking more complex layouts I find `ace-swap-windows` from the [ace-window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) package is also quite handy.

Answer (score 7):

You can roll your own as @Tyler suggested, but there are some packages that support this. Check out the transpose-frame package on MELPA: https://melpa.org/#/transpose-frame

This handles the simple 2-window case, but can also handle more complex arrangements where you flip or rotate the windows around.

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried the `transpose-frame` package so I don't know how it compares, but I use the package https://melpa.org/#/rotate .  Combined that with https://melpa.org/#/smartrep using the config:

```
  (use-package smartrep
    :config
    (setq smartrep-mode-line-active-bg nil))

  (use-package rotate
    :config
    (smartrep-define-key global-map "C-|"
    '(("w" . rotate-window)
      ("l" . rotate-layout))))
```

And then `C-|` `w` `w` `w` `w...` etc. rotates through assigning buffers to windows, and `C-|` `l` `l` `l` `l...` etc. rotates through layouts (such as your use case of flipping between a vertical and horizontal split).

Answer (score 2):

I use C-x 0 (or C-x 1) and then C-x 4 b.  The buffer I just closed is offered as the default, so it is still quick to do.

Comment: That doesn't "switch between horizontal and vertical splitting"; it just gives you the default split.

Comment: @phil I think @Dan was referring to the "note" section of question where I say I was reselecting the buffer. The trick is to use `C-x 4 b`, but yes, that does not solve the problem.